# How to obtain time stamps for messages with no header

Tags: ros, timestamp, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a simple question.

My problem is the following. I am listening to the [move_base/cancel](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) topic because I want to know the exact time at which a certain goal has been canceled.

The [message](http://docs.ros.org/api/actionlib_msgs/html/msg/GoalID.html) I get from this topic is not of the stamped type. I guess that a simple solution would to call:

```
ros::Time stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

as first line of the callback.

However, I guess that the time this call is executed is not the same when the message has been sent.

For this reason, I was considering the idea of using a [timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) combined with a [waitForMessage](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html#a71f090ff64d42348016fa3aecb654ca6) call.

Therefore, my question is: does this make sense? If yes, how do I obtain the time stamp?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328272/how-to-obtain-time-stamps-for-messages-with-no-header/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-11**:
As far as I'm aware, if a message doesn't have a header (or timestamp anywhere else) then it is not possible to determine when it was sent. Without a header the best you'll be able to do is what you've already got recording the time of receipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless something has changed, there is no way to find out when a message was sent if it doesn't have a `Header` (note that even with a `Header` it would not tell you when the message was sent, as any value could be set in the `stamp` field).

> The [message](http://docs.ros.org/api/actionlib_msgs/html/msg/GoalID.html) I get from this topic is not of the stamped type. I guess that a simple solution would to call:

> ```
> ros::Time stamp = ros::Time::now();
> ```

> as first line of the callback.

That would get you the time your callback was called, not when the message was sent (nor when it was received).

> However, I guess that the time this call is executed is not the same when the message has been sent.

Exactly.

> For this reason, I was considering the idea of using a [timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) combined with a [waitForMessage](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html#a71f090ff64d42348016fa3aecb654ca6) call.

I don't understand how this would get you the time the message was sent.

---

If the receipt time would be good enough, you could use a callback with a [MessageEvent](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#MessageEvent_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D), instead of the 'raw' message.

One of the fields in the `MessageEvent` is the `receipt_time`, which is the time the message was received by your node and stored in the message queue. That's still not the time the message was sent, but would seem to be the closest you could get without adding `Header`s to messages that don't have them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1